# How to get Folder size and number of Files avaliable from Folder path in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, video-player

i am trying to create a video player app using kotlin , First of all I got the videos files by using MediaStore , than store this in ArrayList so far it's been perfect but When I made a folder list of videos, I tried to find out the size of those folders and how many video files there are in those folders, but I failed. like this (Image)
[Check this image for more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DvKm.jpg)

This is my data class code (VideoItem.Kt)

```
import android.net.Uri

data class VideoItem(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val duration: Long = 0,
    val folderName: String,
    val size: String,
    val path: String,
    val dateAdded: String,
    val artUri: Uri
)

data class FolderItem(
    val id: String,
    val folderName: String,
    val folderSize: Long
)
```

This is my MainActivity Code To get Allvideos Using MediaStore

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    companion object {
        lateinit var videoList: ArrayList<VideoItem>
        lateinit var folderList: ArrayList<FolderItem>
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        folderList = ArrayList()
        videoList = getAllVideos()
        setFragment(VideoviewFragment())
    }

    private fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayout, fragment)
        transaction.disallowAddToBackStack()
        transaction.commit()
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle", "Range")
    private fun getAllVideos(): ArrayList<VideoItem> {
        val tempList = ArrayList<VideoItem>()
        val tempFolderList = ArrayList<String>()
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_ID
        )
        val cursor = this.contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
        )
        if (cursor != null)
            if (cursor.moveToNext())
                do {
                    val titleC =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE))
                    val idC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID))
                    val folderNameC =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME))
                    val folderIdC =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_ID))
                    val sizeC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE))
                    val pathC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))
                    val dateAddedC =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED))
                    val durationC =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION))
                            .toLong()

                    try {
                        val file = File(pathC)
                        val artUriC = Uri.fromFile(file)
                        val video = VideoItem(
                            title = titleC,
                            id = idC,
                            folderName = folderNameC,
                            size = sizeC,
                            path = pathC,
                            duration = durationC,
                            dateAdded = dateAddedC,
                            artUri = artUriC
                        )
                        if (file.exists()) tempList.add(video)

                        //for adding Folders
                        if (!tempFolderList.contains(folderNameC)) {
                            tempFolderList.add(folderNameC)
                            val folderSizeC = getFileLength(pathC)
                            folderList.add(
                                FolderItem(
                                    id = folderIdC,
                                    folderName = folderNameC,
                                    folderSize = folderSizeC
                                )
                            )
                        }

                    } catch (_: Exception) {
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        cursor?.close()
        return tempList
    }

    private fun getFileLength(path: String?): Long {
        return if (!isExistFile(path)) 0 else File(path.toString()).length()
    }

    private fun isExistFile(path: String?): Boolean {
        val file = File(path.toString())
        return file.exists()
    }
}
```

This is my RecyclerviwAdapter Code(FolderAdapter.kt)

```
class FoldersAdapter(private val context: Context, private var foldersList: ArrayList<FolderItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FoldersAdapter.MyHolder>() {

    class MyHolder(binding: FolderItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val folderName = binding.folderName
        val noofFiles = binding.nooffiles
        val folderSize = binding.foldersize
        val root = binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        return MyHolder(FolderItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.folderName.text = foldersList[position].folderName
        val size: Long = foldersList[position].folderSize
        holder.folderSize.text = android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize(context, (size))
        holder.root.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, FolderVideosActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("position", position)
            ContextCompat.startActivity(context, intent, null)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return foldersList.size
    }


}
```

This is my all codes now please check out all code and suggest the best.

Thank you

Comment: What is 'the folder size'?

Comment: `, but I failed. like this (Image)` ?? I see nothing wrong. What is wrong? What failed?

Comment: `val folderSizeC = getFileLength(pathC)` ? Why not `val folderSizeC = sizeC`? But... You see that folderSizeC becomes the file size of ONE file?

Comment: foldr size means size of avaliable all videos in folder (ex. foldrA contains 9 videos so the size of 9 videos is foldersize )

Comment: val folderSizeC = getFileLength(pathC)  not work properly

Comment: but I failed. like this (Image) this is the exmple, what iam telling

Comment: Again: what is wrong with that image? Nice image. What do you see what we dont see?

Comment: image is not mandetary , mainthing is in the image like folder size and number of files showing , how to show those

Comment: please check underline things

Comment: Well for the last time: what is wrong with that image?

Comment: why you are only tellm about image and only image , again and again told you that how to get folders size and number of files from folder (check the code), can you than help, get videos from android then get folders of videos but main problem is i dont know how to get thos folder size and number of files in folder like shown in image

Comment: Well if you cannot answer a simple question about a remark at an image then it makes little sense trying to handle a problem.

Comment: Ok sorry for my mistake, now sir please help me and tell me hoe to get folder size and number of folder avaliable in folder from above codes

Answer (score 0):

**Use this function for size**

```
private  fun getFolderSize(f: File): Long {
        var size: Long = 0
        if (f.isDirectory) {
            for (file in f.listFiles()!!) {
                size += getFolderSize(file)
            }
        } else {
            size = f.length()
        }
        return size
    }
```

**And Count number of files Use this**

```
val length = File("/path/to/folder").listFiles()?.size
```

Comment: **Use this function for size** this function showing wrong size like folder contains 18 videos but size showing 385kB  And  **Count number of files Use this** this Function return null

Comment: **getFolderSize** this function showing only frist video size of folder , not calculate all videos size

Comment: please help me please help